# I need help thinking about how to split a data frame to perform operations

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, reshape, dplyr

I'm new to R and having a difficult time thinking about the right way to approach a problem. I'm used to doing most of my data analysis in excel, so I think I'm stuck in spreadsheetland. Now I'm getting into data that's too large to do comfortably in excel, so I wanted to step into the light and use R. Thanks in advance for any help you have.

So lets use ChickWeight as an example:

```
> head(ChickWeight)
  weight Time Chick Diet
1     42    0     1    1
2     51    2     1    1
3     59    4     1    1
4     64    6     1    1
5     76    8     1    1
6     93   10     1    1
```

Say I want to be able to split the data frame by both diet and time point such that it would be easy to generate a table of average weights with Time for columns and Diet for rows. Something like:

```
  0   2   4   6 (time)
1   
2    <average weights
3         go in here>
4
(diet)
```

In my head, the easiest way to do this would be to generate a 2d array containing these values so that I can access them like `average_weight[<Time>][<Diet>]`.

I would like to to be easy to also access all of the average weights for a given time or a given diet using something like `average_weight[<Time>][]`

I've gotten the sense that I'm not thinking about this problem right, because none of the tools I've found seem to point me in the right direction. The closest I've gotten is using `split()`

```
chicks_by_time_and_diet <- split(ChickWeight, list(ChickWeight$Time, ChickWeight$Diet))
```

But this returns a list of length 55, not a two-dimensional array. I've also tried looking into `plyr`. This sounded like it was exactly what I wanted, but it's unclear to me exactly how to use it towards this end.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Bonus:
In reality my data frame has many more factors than ChickWeight, and if it were possible to access all of the factors for a given 'Time' and 'Diet', that would be ideal.

E.g. pretend that ChickWeight has another factor, `height`. Would it be possible to store both the average `height` and `weight` for a given diet at a particular location in the array such that `average_weight_and_height[<Time>][<Diet>]` returns a list of `(weight, height)`?

Comment: I'd recommend reading about tidy data, http://www.jstatsoft.org/v59/i10/paper, it will help you understand how to store data most naturally in R.

Comment: Thanks for the paper, @hadley. Just FYI, that link should point to `http://www.jstatsoft.org/v59/i10/paper`. For some reason it doesn't seem to work without the `www.` in the front. 

Edit: nvm that seems to be a problem with the auto-formatting on stackoverflow's part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tapply` is made just for this:

```
> with(ChickWeight, tapply(weight, list(Time, Diet), mean))
           1     2     3        4
0   41.40000  40.7  40.8  41.0000
2   47.25000  49.4  50.4  51.8000
4   56.47368  59.8  62.2  64.5000
6   66.78947  75.4  77.9  83.9000
8   79.68421  91.7  98.4 105.6000
10  93.05263 108.5 117.1 126.0000
12 108.52632 131.3 144.4 151.4000
14 123.38889 141.9 164.5 161.8000
16 144.64706 164.7 197.4 182.0000
18 158.94118 187.7 233.1 202.9000
20 170.41176 205.6 258.9 233.8889
21 177.75000 214.7 270.3 238.5556
```

You can also use `data.table` or `dplyr`, though you will need to reshape the results of those to get to the 2D (or 3D) formats:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(ChickWeight)[, mean(weight), by=.(Time, Diet)]
dcast.data.table(DT, Time ~ Diet)
```

Or, as Arun points out (here we just use a normal data frame):

```
reshape2::dcast(ChickWeight, Time ~ Diet, value.var="weight", fun.aggregate=mean)
```

A lot of R analysis involves getting comfortable with data in "long format" (see `DT` before we `dcast` it), where dimensions are represented by columns.

Comment: Wow, that's exactly the tool I needed. Thank you so much! I'm surprised I never came across this while searching for ways to do this.

Comment: @Arun, I realize.  I left the original statement b/c the seeing data.table used for standard split/grouping is likely useful to a novice.  I then just used `dcast` for the next example as there was no need to convert ChickWeight to `data.table` for that.

Answer (score 4):

Using `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
ChickWeight %>% 
       group_by(Time, Diet) %>% 
       summarise(weight=mean(weight)) %>%
       spread(Time, weight)
```

Comment: So I've noticed that a lot of R's syntax is rather obtuse. It doesn't help that typing %>% into google doesn't work. Do you have any advice for trying to get over this learning curve? Do I just need to commit the hours into reading through manpage after manpage?

Comment: @DanBurkhardt Though reading is needed, it is more practice, trying to solve questions posted in stackoverflow/R mailing list etc. helps.